# How to check if an image exists and delete it using PHP

Tags: php

Its been almost 8 hours i am struggling with this. I have the code below in my PHP file editAuthor.php that allows me to upload an image among other input fields in a specific directory. In my case this directory is (/uploads/authorAvatars/).

The problem is that when I submit the form and it is already an existing image for the specific author I edit, instead of replace this image with the new I selected in my input type file, it creates a new one and adds it in the directory. So if I click the submit button 5 times it will create 5 images instead of one. The filename of the image is stored in the column "avatar" of the table "authors".

I tried to check with PHP if the input file is not empty so i can unlink the existed image but it doesn't work. I am really out of ideas.

Here is my code:

```
// Process the uploaded avatar image
if (isset($_FILES['authoravatar']) && $_FILES['authoravatar']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK ) {
$avatarFile = $_FILES['authoravatar'];
$authorAvatar = isset($author["avatar"]) ? $author["avatar"] : '';
$avatarImage = $avatarDirectory . $authorAvatar;

if ($_FILES['authoravatar']['error'] == 4 || ($_FILES['authoravatar']['size'] == 0 && $_FILES['authoravatar']['error'] == 0)) {
unlink($avatarImage);
}

// Extract the file extension
$fileExtension = pathinfo($avatarFile['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Generate the avatar image filename
$imageFilename = $authorID . "_avatar_" . basename($avatarFile['name']);

// Move the uploaded file to the avatar directory
$destination = $avatarDirectory . $imageFilename;

move_uploaded_file($avatarFile['tmp_name'], $destination);


// Update the avatar database record with the image filename
$stmt = $connection->prepare("UPDATE authors SET avatar = ? WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("si", $imageFilename, $authorID);
$stmt->execute();

}
```

I am literally running out of ideas. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I also tried `if ($authorAvatar) { unlink($avatarImage);}` but didn't work either.

Comment: For what you want to accomplish - you should first check your db record for the current filename and delete the existing file (check if it exists- using `file_exists`), then update the recod with the new filename

Comment: _"it didn't work"_ is not a problem description. Explain **what** happened, what you expected to happen,, and include any error messages you see, or find in the server error log.

Comment: I don't get any error. The problem  is that it saves as many images as the times i click the submit form button instead of replace the existing image as I described in my post. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition to delete the existing avatar image file is contingent on the uploaded file being invalid, so `unlink` will never be called during a successful upload.

```php
$_FILES['authoravatar']['error'] == 4 // no file uploaded (UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE)
// or
$_FILES['authoravatar']['error'] == 0 // no error during file upload (UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
$_FILES['authoravatar']['size'] == 0 // uploaded file was empty
```

The order of operations should ensure that the file was saved successfully as well.

```php
if (isset($_FILES['authoravatar']) && $_FILES['authoravatar']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $avatarFile = $_FILES['authoravatar'];

    // Generate the avatar image filename
    $imageFilename = $authorID . '_avatar_' . basename($avatarFile['name']);

    // Move the uploaded file to the avatar directory
    $destination = $avatarDirectory . $imageFilename;

    $isSaved = move_uploaded_file($avatarFile['tmp_name'], $destination);
    if ($isSaved) {
        // Update the avatar database record with the image filename
        $stmt = $connection->prepare('UPDATE authors SET avatar = ? WHERE id = ?');
        $stmt->bind_param('si', $imageFilename, $authorID);
        $stmt->execute();
        
        // verify pre-existing avatar from Author data
        if (isset($author["avatar"])) {
            $avatarImage = $avatarDirectory . $author['avatar'];
            // ensure a file exists and the directory has permissions
            if (is_file($avatarImage) && is_writable(dirname($avatarImage))) {
                // delete the old avatar image from the filesystem
                unlink($avatarImage);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the intention is to delete the existing avatar image file when the `file` form field is empty, you would need an additional `unlink` call.

```
if (!isset($_FILES['authoravatar']) || 
    UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE === $_FILES['authoravatar']['error'] || 
    0 === $_FILES['authoravatar']['size']) {
    // verify pre-existing avatar from Author data
    if (isset($author["avatar"])) {
        $avatarImage = $avatarDirectory . $author['avatar'];
        // ensure a file exists and the directory has permissions
        if (is_file($avatarImage) && is_writable(dirname($avatarImage))) {
            // delete the old avatar image from the filesystem
            unlink($avatarImage);
        }
    }
}
```